# How do I configure RRAS 2008 so that it only allows domain computers to connect?

Tags: windows-server-2008, rras

I'd like to configure RRAS 2008 so that when a VPN connection is initiated, a check is carried out to verify whether the initiating machine is a member of 'Domain Computers'.

(We're currently experiencing problems with users using their user credentials to connect with other devices to the VPN.)

regards,
  Evert

Answer (score 2):

If you change your VPN connection to use L2TP then it will require a certificate from the client.

Both these articles contain details about the implementation of this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687804(v=ws.10).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687750(v=ws.10).aspx

Alternately you can use a Network Policy Server policy, but this requires a RADIUS server.